# Firebase Dynamic Links for iOS work for my device and simulators, but do not work for users after release

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links, ios-universal-links

So I have implemented Firebase Dynamic Links in my app. I thought that I had them set up correctly, because they work for my own personal device and the simulators perfectly. I released the update to the app, but when two of my friends tried to open them after updating to the new version, it takes them to the Firebase website citing an error. I click the same link and it opens my app and handles the link.

Firebase has added the apple app site association to my domain prefix, I have added the a--link in my app's capabilities, I am truly at a loss as to why this may be. Even if they click the link from notes, it does not give them the option to open the link with my app like it will for me.

Is there anything that I could be overlooking? Happy to supply any relevant details but I feel like I have to be missing something.

App Links:
applinks:share.***.app

URL Type is set up in Target Info.
Custom Dynamic Domain is set in info.plist.

[image: AASA Validated]

Comment: did u add `Associated Domains` in your .entitlements file? also note: - path's works until first match, so be careful within setting multiply values

Comment: Yes, my .entitlements file has the Associated Domains and it shows up as being included in the Archive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others that come across this, it seems to be an open Apple bug: http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=4999496467480576

After several days, the user's apps downloaded the proper AASA and the deep links began to work. There doesn't seem to be a workaround with Google Dynamic Links, but Branch.io offers forced URI redirect mode to avoid this issue.